# alias: /usr/local/bin/pip3: not found, but .bashrc is correct

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to create alias from `pip` to `pip3`.
I followed [this tutorial](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) exactly.
The section 
**Don't forget to update pip to pip3!** is what I followed.

I installed python3 through brew, and `which pip3` gives me `/usr/local/bin/pip3`

I checked  `~/.bashrc` and it has the line below correctly.

```
alias pip= /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

But when I do `source ~/.bashrc` to apply the new code, it gives me

```
-bash: alias: /usr/local/bin/pip3: not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `alias pip='/usr/local/bin/pip3'` in .bashrc or just `ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: I think the space after `=` is causing your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spacing is very important in bash.
Change

```
   alias pip= /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

to

```
   alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

It will work fine.

Comment: I did not know spacing is very important in bash. Thanks!